# MySQL DELETE FROM AS

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a certain kind of duplicates from a table which will can be selected by this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `articles` AS t1 
 WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT `id` 
                  FROM articles AS t2 
                 WHERE t2.link = t1.link AND 
                       t2.id > t1.id
               );
```

So I tried those two queries but they also don't seem to work:

```
DELETE FROM `articles` AS t1 
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT `id` FROM articles AS t2 
               WHERE t2.link = t1.link AND 
                     t2.id > t1.id
              );
```

&

```
DELETE FROM t1 USING `articles` AS t1 
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT `id` 
                FROM `articles` AS t2 
               WHERE t2.link = t1.link AND 
                     t2.id > t1.id
              );
```

both return a syntax error.

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use multiple tables in your `from` clause:

```
DELETE t1
FROM   `articles` t1 , `articles` t2
WHERE  t2.link = t1.link AND t2.id > t1.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
delete
from articles using articles,
    articles a1
where articles.id > a1.id
    and articles.link = a1.link
```